# Le mot « occase »

Tags: vocabulaire, argot

J’ai besoin de votre conseil pour le mot *occase*. J’ai découvert sur le Wiktionnaire qu’il s’agit d’une variante raccourcie du mot « occasion ». Ce dernier peut être utilisé partout tandis qu’« occase » est un peu argotique. Il y a beaucoup de dictionnaires en ligne qui disent la même chose.

Mais ça ne veut pas dire que tout français connait ce mot. J’ai peu d’espoir qu’elle soit utilisée à l’écrit, car en recourant à un moteur de recherche, j’ai presque uniquement trouvé des explications de ce mot, et une poignée de titres qui le contenaient. Selon  *Google Ngram Viewer*, le pourcentage de l’emploi d’« occase » parmi les autres mots français est réduit à 0.0000025%, ce qui me déçoit encore plus : Je me sers plus souvent de cet outil, et si je vois un tel nombre, je crains que tout le monde soit étonné d’entendre ce mot, et qu’il rendrait flou ce que je dis.

Cependant, rien exclut que je me trompe, et que des amis qui bavardent familièrement disent ce mot volontiers, comme « petit-déj’ » et « y-a pas de souci ».

Ça va si je dis quelque chose comme une des phrases suivantes ?

- « Quel dommage ! j’ai raté la dernière occase pour devenir sapeur-pompier. »
- « Ceci est la seule occase qu’on ait, donc il faut la saisir ».

Ce serait très utile si vous décriviez quelles choses ces phrases éveillent chez vous.

Comment: Le corpus français de google ngrams, c'est de l'écrit. Tu ne trouveras presque aucun argot ou tournures orales sauf cas exceptionnel où ils apparaitraient dans des propos rapportés.

Comment: 'Mais ça ne veut pas dire que tout français connait ce mot' Je n'ai jamais rencontré une personne qui ne connaisse pas ce mot.

Comment: @sliders_alpha Enchanté. Je le vois au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/occase), je note aussi l'adjectif en astronomie... Milieu 19ème pour l'aspect commercial, autres usages 20ème.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Occase* est très utilisé à l'oral, c'est plutôt familier et ça signifie bien « occasion ». En général on l'utilise pour désigner une bonne affaire, une aubaine (« C'est l'occase du siècle !! ») ou dans le sens « pas neuf » (comme dans « voiture d'occase », c'est-à-dire « d'occasion »). Mais cela n'empêche pas d'autres emplois, par exemple : « On se reverra à l'occase ».

Answer (score 1):

Being French, I can tell you that everyone understands this word.
Also note that *occase* can be written *occaz* (it has more hits on Google).

Comment: "Occaz" ? Seriously ? Never seen it like that except as a wordplay for brands or by young people hiding their lack of knowledge by writing words as they hear. "Occase" is already more oral than written speach, so if you really want to write it, I would rather use the "usual" writing of it, which even leads to correct (English) translations when you google it...

Comment: ["Occaz" is used](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/occaz) (as many words which are written phonetically nowadays) but the standard writing would be ["occase"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/occase) (or maybe sometimes "occas'" (with an `'` to show an elision). The latter is however unlikely nowadays.